# When choosing "In need of moderator intervention" post flag reason, the input field is no longer auto-focused

Tags: bug, flags, user-experience, flag-dialog, focus

The comment flag "Something else" option will auto-focus the text input field when selected. But the same is not true for the "In need of moderator intervention" flag reason for post flags. I've tripped over this every single time I've tried to use that flag reason recently. I have keyboard shortcuts activated, so when I trip, I often activate a bunch of other keyboard shortcuts unintentionally and it's a bit of a janky experience.

I know you can press space to select the flag reason items if they have tab focus. I'd like this to happen for that case as well.

Sorry if this is a duplicate. I tried searching "`flag focus input`" and "`focus [flag-dialog] is:q`" in the searchbar and didn't see anything that looked like a duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, auto focus should be trivial thing, sadly in SE it's not and very much inconsistent. e.g. it does auto focus in "add comment", it doesn't auto focus upon "edit tags" as expected, and much more such examples. That's due to each developer working in their own "style", and lack of clear policy from above. :/

Comment: Retagged as a bug, as this used to work. Chances are that a change to CSS class names broke this.