# Make clicking "add/edit private note" in the saves view auto-focus the text input for the private note

Tags: feature-request, saves, focus

After clicking "add/edit private note", the text input for the private note appears, but it isn't focused automatically. I don't like having to move my user-agent's focus (either by pointer or keyboard) to the text input manually. It's particularly bothersome when doing bulk edits. Please focus it automatically.

This kind of problem seems to be a little chronic (see also [Upon click of the "In need of moderator intervention" post flag reason, auto-focus the text input field](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388352/997587) and [Auto-focus the revealed text input upon clicks on the filter button in the review queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420202/11107541)). It would be nice for it to be addressed more systematically throughout the whole site, but for now I'll settle for case-by-case requests.

Comment: Would be awesome if there was a keyboard-shortcut way of submitting the dialog as well; `Ctrl+Enter` doesn't submit right now, which is unfortunate.

Comment: @zcoop98 in the saves page, pressing enter submits the private note. in Q&A pages, you need to press tab (to get to the submit button) and then enter.